# Java 8 Read File + Stream

Tags: java, java-8

I want to read a file line by line using Java 8 Stream
I have this piece of code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/viewlog" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public String viewLoad(final ModelMap model) throws IOException {
    System.out.println ("reading file from userHome -> " + userHome);
    String content = null;
    try {
        content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(userHome + "/logs/nicinc/nicinc.log")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println ("Exception e -> " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.out.println ("content -> " + content);
    }
    //System.out.println ("content -> " + content);
    return serverContextPath +  SYSTEM_LOG_VIEW;
}
```

But this is what I got from the console, that it really makes no sense for me:

```
65630 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/nicinc] threw exception
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\carbonelllogs\nicinc\nicinc.log
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you are running the same code as the path must have `/logs/` or `\logs\` in it.

Comment: `carbonelllogs` you are missing a separator...

Comment: userHome  is missing "\" in the end

Comment: @JNomad you don't need it there, one is present in `/logs...`

Comment: Why not using `Paths.get(userHome, "logs/nicinc/nicinc.log")` instead of dealing with string concatenation and separators manually?

Answer (score 3):

The file you are looking for is missing a path seperator.

```
C:\Users\carbonelllogs\nicinc\nicinc.log
```

should be

```
C:\Users\carbonell\logs\nicinc\nicinc.log
```

the most likely explanation is that you have fixed the code at some point, but haven't redeployed it successfully.